# Connect/check availability of a wired device without using a ping command

Tags: linux, networking

```
How to connect/check availability of a wired device without using a ping command ?
```

Actually I want to check connection to a wired device in the same LAN. But ping command gives me 40% to 50% loss. So is there any other way to check the connection in Linux ?

Comment: strcitly speaking, with (some) loss the device is still connected. I'd use fping, for its better scriptability. Consider that it's not ping's fault if there is packet loss - ping is only the messenger which you are about to shoot

Answer (score 1):

Off course,

`sudo apt-get install nmap`

Then use host discovery

`nmap -sn 192.1.68.0/24`

More info
`man nmap`